# DocuSign API: Specify Signature Image for Embedded Recipient (captive recipient)

Tags: docusignapi

Our Docusign integration is such that a user has a Docusign account, can create an envelope, and they become an embedded signer on the new envelope.

The embedded signer is assigned a `clientUserId` and this causes a signature image to be assigned to them.

However, this user has an existing signature image that they would like to use (their `signatureId` is known).

I know it is possible to delete a signature image for a captive recipient using the [Accounts: deleteCaptiveRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/deleteCaptiveRecipient/) endpoint. However, the description states that it "provides a way to reset the signature associated with a client user ID so that a **new** signature can be created the next time the client user ID is used."

I'm interested in assigning an **existing** signature image that is associated with the user's Docusign account to this embedded recipient.

Is it possible to set a signature image for an embedded recipient?

Edit: Since it is not possible to do so, I have 2 follow up questions:

1) Due to our integration, a user may be an embedded recipient on many envelopes (ie on every envelope they create).

Would the `deleteCaptiveRecipient` not be suitable since there is no way to identify a unique embedded recipient by ID (ie only update one embedded recipient)?

2) If the user is assigned a new `clientUserId`, is their old signature image will still be available if the previous `clientUserId` is assigned again?

Thus, option 2 seems to be the better option for our integration (since it is per envelope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API call to associate Signature image to a signer. Signature needs to be done as a Human activity only. Now embedded Signers are considered as accountless signers and DocuSign never checks if that signer has a DocuSign account or not if you have assigned that signer as an embedded signer, so DocuSign will not show the user's account signature image. There is no way to set a signature image for an embedded recipient.

For #1, Ideally you should use same clientUserId for same recipient, as clientUserId is an index on DocuSign tables so it is quick to fetch the data if same clientUserId is used again and again in different envelopes. Normally, we suggest to use employeeNumber, or any unique userId for that recipient in your system for clientUserId. This way same clientUserId will be used across all the envelopes for the same embedded recipient. If its not possible to use any of the above then you can use emailId in clientUserId that way also same clientUserId, name and email will be used across all the envelopes sent to that embedded signer.

For #2, For embedded signing, as long as you pass the same name/email@/clientUserID for a specific individual, DocuSign will remember the signature they adopted and re-apply it for future signature events.

Comment: Thank you, Amit. I have added follow-up questions to my original post.

Comment: Update my answer for your queries